# Cannot run collect after using reduceByKey()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to learn Pyspark and I can not run a basic program and I can't figure out what's the problem. when I try to call collect on m it prints as expected put can not call collect on s.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from array import array
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np 
from __future__ import print_function
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
def f(x):
    temp  = {}
    y=0
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        for j in range( i+1 , len(x)):
            if( x[i][0] == x[j][0]):
                #print(j,i)
                y = y+1

        temp2 = {x[i][0]: y}
        if x[i][0] in temp.keys():

            y=0
            continue
        temp.update(temp2)
        y=0       
    return temp           


t  = (("Tim","bob") , ("kevin", "bob") , ("viki", "tom") , ("mahesh" , "viki") , ("ramesh", "tom") )
rdd = sc.parallelize(t)

m = rdd.map(lambda x : (x[1],x[0]))
s = m.reduceByKey(lambda x: x)
print(s.collect())
#s = m.collect()
sc.stop()
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()

Comment: it clearly says that there is some error at line 337

Comment: I managed to run it.

Comment: In line with protocol to be nice to new persons, it is equally a code of conduct to respond to effort.

Comment: @etl_devs  377, not 337

Answer (score 0):

Suggest this:

```
s = m.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

Comment: Not sure what the def is doing in relation to the question at hand.